# Changing inner html of a div and adding an image to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue. When I try to change the inner html of div and putting an img source into that div's innerhtml it doesn't display the image

My javascript code:

```
var sliderimg = document.getElementById('abc_'+obj).src;
$("#event-img").html("<img src=sliderimg>");
```

When I try to alert it gives me object object error.

Could someone please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var sliderimg = document.getElementById('abc_'+obj).src;
$("#event-img").html("<img src='"+sliderimg+"' />");
```

You need to escape the quote marks to ensure sliderimg is seen as a variable rather than a string. and you were missing a close tag

Comment: I didn't see that you were referencing a variable, i've edited the example, please try this.